# spring testRestTemplate basic auth not working for POST requests Httpstatus 302

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-test

I am using Spring's `org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate` for testing controller code.

I can test the GET APIs simply by using `testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("test", "test").exchange(...)`, but the same way isn't working for the POST endpoints in same controller.

It returns HttpStatus `302 found` with the following ResponseEntity:

```
<302,[Set-Cookie:"JSESSIONID=332C559B7CABE5682EE9910A6FF834DA; Path=/; HttpOnly", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Location:"http://localhost:61598/login", Content-Length:"0", Date:"Thu, 09 Jul 2020 14:24:18 GMT", Server:"Application Server"]>
```

Code of controller:

```java
  @GetMapping(value = "/filterable_columns", produces = "application/json")
  public List<FilterableField> filterableFieldList() {
    log.info("Received request for list of filterable fields");
    return metaDataService.filterableFieldList(referenceDataService.getSchemaUri());
  }


  @PostMapping(value = "/search", produces = "application/json")
  public List<Map<String, Object>> filteredSearch(@RequestBody FilteredSearchRequest filteredSearchRequest) throws IllegalAccessException {
    log.info("Received request for filtered search");
    return referenceDataService.filteredSearch(filteredSearchRequest);
  }
```

Controller Test:

```java
  @Test // This works as expected
  void filterableFieldList() {
    val reply = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("test", "test")
      .exchange("/reference_data/filterable_columns",
        HttpMethod.GET, null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FilterableField>>() {
        });

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, reply.getStatusCode());
    assertFalse(Objects.requireNonNull(reply.getBody()).isEmpty());
  }

  @Test // This does not work
  void filteredSearch() {
    val reply = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("test", "test")
      .exchange("/reference_data/search",
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new HttpEntity<>(new FilteredSearchRequest()),
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        }
      );
    System.out.println(reply);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, reply.getStatusCode());
  }
```

AdfsSecurityConfiguration.java:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "moneta.security.adfs", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class AdfsSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final Environment environment;
  private final AdfsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> adfsConfigurer;

  public AdfsSecurityConfiguration(final Environment environment, final AdfsConfigurer<HttpSecurity> adfsConfigurer) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.adfsConfigurer = adfsConfigurer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if (!isRunningLocally()) {
      http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
    http.apply(adfsConfigurer).and()
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and().authorizeRequests()
      .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("keepalive", "info", "health", "env"), EndpointRequest.toLinks())
      .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
  }

  private boolean isRunningLocally() {
    return environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("default"));
  }
}
```

application-test.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: test
      password: test
```

Comment: can you add your full test setup and the code of your controller endpoint?

Comment: @rieckpil, updated in question description

Comment: can you also add your Spring Security configuration?

Comment: @rieckpil updated again